For OpenSSH on Windows, what is an alternative to nohup / screen / tmux
I have an OpenSSH Server on my Windows 11 machine and can run programs from PowerShell when I connect using some SSH client.
However, when I disconnect, anything running in the background on the Windows machine, started from the SSH session, terminates as well. I've looked at Start-Process, Start-Job, and PS-Session but it appears that as soon as I end my SSH session, the started process ends as well.
On Linux, I'm somewhat familiar with nohup, screen, and tmux - but I'm not aware of anything similar for Windows.
Is there a way to start a process on Windows from an OpenSSH PowerShell session that allows the process to continue running after I disconnect - either with the option of reconnecting later, or just stopping the process in some other way?

duplicate: Detach program from SSH connection on a windows

However, the answer there is wrong, as far as I can tell - it's something I tried before posting here, where it seems more appropriate. It looks like it is simply not possible though. One thing that sort of works is starting a process as a service if you have elevation, but clearly that's useless for many use cases.
